# How to set size Maui window desktop responsively

Tags: c#, maui, responsive

I'm working on an windows MAUI App and I have no idea how to size the windows responsively with the screen of the user. this the property of the app. I ve tried many tutorials and nothing efficient.
here's my program.cs

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureMopups()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

#if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif
        //builder.Services.AddDbContext<SqliteDbContext>(options =>
        //  options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        builder.UseFoldable();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRestService<SocieteUser>, RestService<SocieteUser>>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<NewAuditViewModel>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<NewAudit>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainMenu>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISocieteUserService, SocieteUserService>();

      

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

I can give more info if its needed .
[image]

thanks by advance

Comment: Did you mean changing the windows size at runtime?

Comment: I mean at the opening of the app. the app take the size of the screen

Comment: Do you want to set the full screen or a custom size of your app? You may try my solution below to either set the full screen of a custom size. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using [Custom lifecycle events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle?view=net-maui-8.0#custom-lifecycle-events) to make your app full screen or a custom size.

Try adding the following code in **MauiProgram.cs**,

```
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
        {
#if WINDOWS
            events.AddWindows(windows =>
            {
                windows.OnWindowCreated(window =>
                {
                    IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
                    WindowId windowId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
                    var appWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
                    
                    //Use presenter to determine the look and feel of the window.                  
                    switch (appWindow.Presenter)
                    {
                        case OverlappedPresenter overlappedPresenter:                                
                            //you could also set to true if you want a titlebar or border
                            overlappedPresenter.SetBorderAndTitleBar(false, false);
                            //set app window full screen
                            overlappedPresenter.Maximize();
                            break;
                    }

                   //or set the custom size for your app window
                   //appWindow.Resize(new Windows.Graphics.SizeInt32(1600, 1200));

                                         
                });
            });
#endif
        });
```

Another way to set the app full screen is using

```
appWindow.SetPresenter(AppWindowPresenterKind.FullScreen);
```

---

By the way, if you want to get the screen info, you may refer to [Device display information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device/display?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=windows).

```
Console.WriteLine(DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Width);
Console.WriteLine(DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Height);
```